# JavaScript - html div as audio source

Tags: javascript, html, audio

i have a problem. I want to make html div that is source of audio. I see it as when i move cursor nearer to div audio will make louder, and when farer it will make quieter. But it has to be limited range to not play audio on whole website

I had idea to make it by cursor x and y, but i think that there is spexiaf function for this
case

Comment: HTML is just a markup language to format texts. It can not be the source of audio. What you need I to bind in some audio and change the volume of the audio played with JS.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: As i write i tried to read all div edges and control pointer distance from div, but i haven't finished it yet